# libpcap drops some packets from specific IP

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

I'm implementing packet collector, but I suffer from packet drops.

My binary can get most of packets from some specific IP region. (Ex. 100.101.1.1, 100.101.2.1). But to some specific IP region, I cannot get any packet. (Ex. 200.201.1.1, 200.201.2.1)

At that time, tcpdump can get packets from any IP regions.

My pcap code snippet from my implementation is followings:

```
struct bpf_program fp;
pcap_t *pcd;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
bpf_u_int32 netp;
char port[16], dev[16];
......
pcd = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, PROMISCUOUS, -1, errbuf);
pcap_compile(pcd, &fp, port, 0, netp);
pcap_setfilter(pcd, &fp);
while(1){
    packet = pcap_next(pcd, &hdr);
}
```

Is there any idea for me?

Comment: add the output of `ifconfig`, and the command-line you use to run tcpdump. Could it be that the IP you're looking for is not on the interface you're opening?

Comment: What is dev?  If you pass null or any instead of dev, you should be able to capture packets from all interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you can get all the ip packets on the interface using *tcpdump*, I would consider the following line in your code is all right as long as you are using the same interface name for the parameter *dev* as you use for *tcpdump*.

```
pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, PROMISCUOUS, -1, errbuf);
```

The issue might be in the line,

```
pcap_compile(pcd, &fp, port, 0, netp);
```

In the above line, *port* variable is a filter string. Your packet collector will only collect the packets that passes this filter. If you are not using proper filter parameters in your *port* string to allow also the packets involving ip addresses *200.201.x.x*, you will not capture them.